# How to remove this type of string #VTkfzCGqqkow from URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, query-string, clean-urls

I am using osCommerce platform. I noticed in Chrome browser; the URLs are not clean and have trailing string like #VTkfzCGqqkow, specially on products pages
for example
www.example.com/product-name.html#VTkfzCGqqkow
while I need clean URLs like
www.example.com/product-name.html

Please suggest me a solution either to modify .htaccess file or osCommercer files.

Thank you.

Comment: Url fragments aren't sent to the server so you won't be able to do it server side

Comment: Please suggest me any solution. As I noticed the URls are clean at the start of page rendering and once the page is loaded completely, Chrome adds this strange hash string out of no where. While this is not a case in firefox and other browsers.

Comment: You have something installed/added to your site that adds that. We can't read your mind

Comment: Nothing added and this string shows only in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
$url = 'www.example.com/product-name.html#VTkfzCGqqkow ';
echo var_export(parse_url($url));
```

You use:

```
$url = parse_url($url,PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Comment: If you want to clean the url, `parse_url` will return the url "path: without the url fragment.  This code goes in the PHP where the url needs to be cleaned.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted this issue, it is happening due to Javascript on client side.
Thank you all for your time and support